# Order by ASC returning weird results

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have the following query :

```
SELECT
x.id,x.title
FROM `x`
WHERE  `x`.status = 'validated'
ORDER BY `x`.title ASC
```

**Results :**

```
3042    Cinéastes en herbe Télé-Québec
1681    Danse contemporaine
2725    Dessins, peinture et illustrations. 
2448    Les petits mots de Paolo
641     Ma tente à lire et les Mosaïques dans la rue
3215    Performance & Visites commentées
2186    Se partager l’espace : Yann Pocreau 
2364    Souper communautaire 
1223    100 ans
199     100% couleurs
2794    125 ans de tourisme à Laval
2306    À court de souffle!
1517    Abracadabra Sonia
2477    Atelier ouvert
335     Au bout du fil
2362    Au coeur de notre mémoire
2489    Bientôt 100 ans!
2275    Café historique 
1838    Rencontre avec
```

Am i missing something ? Why the title is not ordered correctly ?

For info :

**Collation :** utf8_general_ci

**Character set :** utf-8

Solution : a hidden space was in the results --> used the trim function

Comment: Hmm... perhaps you use some exotic collation on this column? :)

Comment: Collation : utf8_general_ci , Character set : utf-8

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would check the first few rows to see if there is a hidden character at the front of the title.

```
SELECT
    ASCII(SUBSTRING(x.title, 1, 1))
FROM
    x
WHERE
    x.id IN (3042, 1681)
```

Comment: +1, though I'd check all rows, and especially `(1517, Abracadabra Sonia)` onwards.

Comment: Yeah it's an idea. Do these characters are the only invisible characters?

Comment: I had a space ... fixed it by adding the trim function

Comment: A guess born out of experience :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are not using the collation you want to. Depending on the collation of your database, strings get ordered differently.